# wordpress : How to set the value of "Select Category" to a value other than 0

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically I show a drop-down of a subcategories of a specific category,now I want if no one select a sub category and click on search then by default it search from only parent category.
I add this this

```
 'show_option_all' => __( 'All Manufacturers', APP_TD ),
```

but its by default value is "0" I want to change its value from "0" to 187.any help plz
here I want to implement [this](http://dynatest.org/pakwheels)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like below;

```
$args = array( 
    'show_option_all' => __( 'All Manufacturers', APP_TD ),
    ..............
    );
$str = wp_list_categories($args);
// or use this
// $str = str_replace('value="0"', 'value="187"', $str);
$str = str_replace("value='0'", "value='187'", $str);
```

Comment: doing  <?php $str=wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); 
      $str = str_replace('value="0"', 'value="187"', $str);?>    this but cannot solve remain "0" value

Comment: Have you got any live site? Or please inspect your category dropdown and show me the html

Comment: @user3035153 see my updated answer. I think you need to replace double quote with single quote `$str = str_replace("value='0'", "value='187'", $str);`